# tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices, tensors and eager mode

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

Using Iris dataset example:

```
train_ds_url = "http://download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_training.csv"
```

Imports used:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
tf.enable_eager_execution()
```

I downloaded the dataset and then I used `pd.read` to represent  `train_plantfeatures`,  `train_categories` arrays.

```
categories='Plants'

train_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file(train_ds_url.split('/')[-1], train_ds_url)

train = pd.read_csv(train_path, names=ds_columns, header=0)
train_plantfeatures, train_categories = train, train.pop(categories)
```

After that I used `tf.contrib.keras.utils.to_categorical` to create the categorical representation.

```
y_categorical = tf.contrib.keras.utils.to_categorical(train_categories, num_classes=3)
```

When I tried to use `tf.data.Dataset` and `from_tensor_slices`

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_plantfeatures, y_categorical))
```

I received:

> ValueError: Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor.

Same implementation without eager mode works perfectly.Here the [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1A6u68SyQqvsjgHhR4vNw7ukcZIgTMzMT) example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `from_tensor_slices()` method receives as input a Numpy array. But in this case, the variable `train_plantfeatures` is a Pandas `DataFrame`.

```
type(train_plantfeatures)
`Out:` pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

To make this work, add `.values` to convert from Pandas to Numpy:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_plantfeatures.values,
                                              y_categorical))
```

Do same for the `test_plantfeatures` variable:

```
dataset_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_plantfeatures.values, 
                                                   y_categorical_test))
```